# Dailymotion Embed Videos aren't generating revenue

Tags: video

Hello I wanted to ask that I have been embeding videos on my site and have great traffic of 10k Weekly and sometimes more then 10k, But I noticed that I'm not earning through those embeded videos. Can u help me in this.

Also If this problem is due to not adding Domain then I have a question that I have adsense enabled on my site, will adding dailymotion ads.txt/Domain have any affect on my site/adsense.

I haven't tried anything bcz I fear it may affect my adsense or site so I'm hoping to find answer here